# Upgrading jax-rs shared library on weblogic

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, weblogic12c

Normally weblogic 12c doesnt support jax-rs 2.0 but by the help of jax-rs shared library which comes with weblogic itself it is possible to upgrade jax-rs version from 1.1 to 2.0. The problem is library implementation is jersey 2.5 which doesnt satisfy my needs. I found a link about upgrading jersey version on weblogic which looks a lil bit complex. Is it enough to replace jersey jars 2.5 with my jersey version 2.13? Do i need to do anything else?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to downgrade the version of jersey? Why not just register the older version as a new shared library? It's only one command line call to register a new shared library https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I wanted to upgrade jersey version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a simple maven project to produce the war file with the 2.19 jersey shared library for weblogic.
I have tested it with weblogic 12.1.3
You can clone from here [weblogic-jax-rs](https://github.com/georgeyanev/weblogic-jax-rs)
After cloning run `mvn package` to produce the war and then deploy it to the server.
Of course you must specify the new implementation version in your weblogic.xml which is now 2.19

If you are not familiar with maven you can download the war file [from here](https://github.com/georgeyanev/weblogic-jax-rs/releases/download/0.1/jersey-shared-lib-2.19.war)

As of weblogic 12.2.1 - there is jersey 2.21.1 bundled with it so no additional installations are required.

weblogic 12.2.1.1 comes with jersey 2.22.1

Comment: Thanks for your war with an updated jersey version. Unfortunately, when I deploy your war in my wls 12.1.3, I get this error:
"weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject"
Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Seems that javassist package is not there. Please use `mvn install` to generate the library war and then make sure javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar is present inside.

Comment: @George, As of weblogic 12.2.1 - there is jersey 2.21.1 bundled with it so no additional installations are required: Is there any way to avoid those references from war file to jersey related libraries on weblogic server as war is already having required jersey related jars?