# Deploying a Jersey application on Weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

I am having difficulty deploying a Jersey application to Weblogic 12, I have spent a lot of time battling with it and am still struggling. I have followed various suggestions on various sites (including this one), but I am still having issues. I don't know if I am fundamentally misunderstanding something basic, so I am hoping someone can help me.

Here is what I have so far:

I have created a new maven project.
Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>uk.co.omnicomengineering</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-weblogic</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jersey-weblogic</name>

<build>
    <finalName>jersey-weblogic</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

I have also deployed the jax-rs to Weblogic as in https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF299 and added the following weblogic.xml to my WEB-INF directory:

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:library-ref>
   <wls:library-name>jax-rs</wls:library-name>
   <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
   <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
```

Now, when I try to deploy the application, I get the following error:

```
<06-Jul-2015 11:19:45 o'clock BST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "Jersey Web Application" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "jersey-weblogic".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:329)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:339)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<06-Jul-2015 11:19:45 o'clock BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "10095322227139" for task "12". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:329)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:339)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<06-Jul-2015 11:19:45 o'clock BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 7 task for the application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<06-Jul-2015 11:19:45 o'clock BST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating start task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<06-Jul-2015 11:19:45 o'clock BST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:329)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:339)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am not really sure what is going wrong; am I using the wrong dependencies in my POM?

Any help that anyone could give would be gratefully received, I have spend a lot of time battling with Weblogic and Jersey!

--EDIT --

I have added the following to my weblogic.xml (following http://www.widecodes.com/CxVkWWgPUj/using-jersey-2x-web-service-on-weblogic-1211.html which seems to be a similar issue):

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<library-ref>
   <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
   <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
   <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>

<container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
    <package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>

    <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</package-name>

    <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>

    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Now, when I deploy I get the following error:

```
<08-Jul-2015 14:16:25 o'clock BST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "Jersey Web Application" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "jersey-weblogic".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:714)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:644)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:822)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:452)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<08-Jul-2015 14:16:26 o'clock BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "193463109842784" for task "12". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:714)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:644)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:822)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:452)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<08-Jul-2015 14:16:26 o'clock BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 7 task for the application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<08-Jul-2015 14:16:26 o'clock BST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating start task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<08-Jul-2015 14:16:26 o'clock BST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:714)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:644)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:822)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:452)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Tell weblogic what jar files to use for your app with `prefer-application-packages`. NoSuchMethodError means you have competing jar files on the class path. See an example like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990633/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida/14936333#14936333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you were trying to deploy jersey as a shared library in WLS initially, I am assuming you were not supplying the jersey jar files with your EAR file, or at least that was not the intent.

1. I suspect the initial problem was that you might have deployed an older version of jax-rs from the deployable library.  What you want to see in your deployments is jax-rs(2.0,2.5.1) - spec 2.0, implementation 2.5.1 - deployed as a shared library.
2. you should not put  in the weblogic.xml unless you want the packages you specified "must always be loaded from the application" (ref [Oracle doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP660)) - i.e. wls would look for these packages provided from your EAR - which I suspect is not what you want to do.  You would only do this if you want to supply your own version of the jersey files - typically later more up to date version than what WLS provides.

I suggest you back out your changes you made on the weblogic.xml, you redeploy the jax-rs shared library, and make sure you did not accidentally included any of the jersey jar files in your EAR.  I am not a maven user, so I'm not sure what you have on the POM file would automatically include these dependent files in your EAR file.  You do not want this if you want to use the WLS versions of jersey.

Also, not sure if this would make a difference, but on my version of weblogic.xml, I included the implementation-version to match that of the shared library.

```
<wls:library-ref>  
    <wls:library-name>jax-rs</wls:library-name>  
    <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:implementation-version>2.5.1</wls:implementation-version>  
    <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
```

Good luck.  These deployment issues can be tricky to maddening.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to resolve the issue based on your suggestions. Maddening is certainly the word!

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know before deploying a JAX-RS application to Weblogic you must install jax-rs shared library on the server. It resides in `$WLHOME/common/deployable-libraries/jax-rs-2.0.war`

After that you should not have any jersey jars on your ear/war application. You just reference the jax-rs library from weblogic.xml preferably with its implementation version. This `<prefer-application-packages>` section is supposed to be defined in the weblogic.xml inside jax-rs library war and not in yours weblogic.xml.

If you want to use more recent version of the jax-rs library check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573827/upgrading-jax-rs-shared-library-on-weblogic/31563812#31563812)